# Binomial Distribution; Using a mean to suggest probability of success.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

and thanks for taking the time to look at my question.
This was for a homework task, on binomial distribution, which i thought i understood.

> A consignment of china mugs is packed for transportation in boxes of
>   six. After the journey, a random sample of 100 boxes was inspected and
>   the number of broken mugs was counted, with the following results:
>   Number of boxes - Number of broken mugs in a box
>   25-0, 41-1, 25-2, 7-3, 2-4, 0-5, 0-6.
>
> Let X be the random variable for the number of broken mugs in a box.
>
> a) Calculate the mean number of broken mugs in a box for the sample of 100 boxes. 
>       The sum of the broken mugs = 120. 
>       120/100 = 1.20.
>       Mean number of broken mugs in a box for the sample of 100 boxes = 1.20.

The next section of the question confuses me:

> b)Explain why a Binomial distribution X ~ Bin(6, p) could be used to model X, and show that  using the mean calculated in (a) as the
>   expected value suggests that the probability of success  p, is equal
>   to 0.2 where ‘success’ is a mug being broken. You should address each
>   of the  assumptions of a Binomial model in your answer.

I understand that the probability of success = 0.2 as 1.2/6 = 0.2, 
but i don't understand how to place this in the binom function in excel to show this. Any insights would be very helpful. 
=BINOMDIST(1.2;6;0.2;1) = 0.655,
=BINOMDIST(6;100;0.012;1) = 0.99
Why do i get the feeling that i'm overlooking something blindingly obvious?

Comment: The data giving the number of boxes that have a particular number of broken mugs does not make sense.  According to what is written, $25$ boxes have $0$ broken mugs, but then you write $5$ boxes and $6$ boxes have $0$ broken mugs.  Please correct the errors.

Comment: Sorry about that, I had the last two numbers back-to-front. fixed it now. Thanks.

Comment: Still flawed.  "7-4" and "2-4" makes no sense.

Comment: I really don't know why i'm incapable of typing :'(.  Hopefully fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample mean of the number of broken mugs in a box is $$\bar x = \frac{25 \cdot 0 + 41 \cdot 1 + 25 \cdot 2 + 7 \cdot 3 + 2 \cdot 4 + 0 \cdot 5 + 0 \cdot 6}{100} = 1.2.$$  Since the expected value of a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$ is ${\rm E}[X] = np$, if we use the estimate $\bar x = 6\hat p$, then $\hat p = \frac{1.2}{6} = 0.2$, as claimed.